# How to install a version of qemu and libvirt that doesn't come with apt-get

Tags: apt, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, versions, qemu

I need to install QEMU 2.5.0 and libvirt 1.3.3 to get around Nvidia driver issues (Code 43) when doing GPU passthrough on a windows VM. See first article under *troubleshooting* in [src](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF) for details.

I've installed KVM using `sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm qemu-utils qemu-efi ovmf libvirt-bin libvirt-de`, they this gives me older versions.

With *virsh* the `version` command prints out:

```
Compiled against library: libvirt 1.3.1
Using library: libvirt 1.3.1
Using API: QEMU 1.3.1
Running hypervisor: QEMU 2.5.0
```

I've fairly new to Ubuntu, so could someone explain how I upgrade or install QEMU 2.5.0 and libvirt 1.3.3 (or a later version)?

Comment: Maybe try a PPA like https://launchpad.net/~jacob/+archive/ubuntu/virtualisation, also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them?s=1|1.2557

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I added the ppa and upgraded the packages.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not an issue related to the version you have/had. There's a few changes to your VM's config (xml file) you have to make to workaround nvidia's deliberate attempt to brick VM functionality on their mainstream/non workstation cards. Make sure there's no virtual display attached to the VM with the virt-manager tool, then

1. Shut down your vm and virt manager
2. Open up a command prompt and type:

   ```
   sudo virsh edit vmnamehere
   ```
3. Replace the very first line with:

   ```
   <domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
   ```

   (You can find the code here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HtXhxTTvjS/)
4. Scroll to the very end of the config file and right before `</domain>`, insert:

   ```
   <qemu:commandline>
     <qemu:arg value='-cpu'/>
     <qemu:arg value='host,hv_time,kvm=off,hv_vendor,hv_vendor_id=null'/>
   </qemu:commandline>
   ```

   (You can find the code here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HtXhxTTvjS/)
5. Save + exit whatever editor you used
6. Restart the virt-manager application

This works for me every time. Hope you didn't give up on this, as I see this is an old post. A good way to see if you're doing things right is to try GPU passthrough on an OS that will for sure work, like a Linux / Ubuntu / Debian VM.

Comment: Small adjustment: QEMU (in the latest version at the time this was written) supports Hyper-V time without having to use the `qemu:arg` notation.  Replace the second `qemu:arg` with `<qemu:arg='host,kvm=off,hv_vendor,hv_vendor_id=null'/>` and add ```<clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>``` - found [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1056205)